# How to trigger resource replacement in Terraform if resource atrtibute changed?

Tags: terraform

So, I'm controlling a bunch of Teams in Sentry through terraform like this:

```
resource "sentry_team" "foo" {
  for_each     = [...]
  organization = ...
  name         = ...
}
```

And I noticed that when I imported the original teams, they had different names than my logic would give them. But apparently, the Sentry provider doesn't do team renaming.
So, I renamed then manually, which caused all kinds of hell on my state.

Then I thought I could use `replace_triggered_by` and reference the name attribute of the Resource, but I found no way that that works.

And honestly replacing the team would not be a great practice either, since that would ruin all existing settings.

But for posterity I'd like to know if there is a way to force an Resource to be replaced if one of its attributes changes?

Comment: This kind of behavior would need to be part of the provider. If the provider is not capable of that, then you would need to `terraform state mv` to correct drift.

Answer (score 1):

how about using lifecycle argument with `null_resource` and `replace_triggered_by`?

```
resource "null_resource" "example" {
  for_each = [...]
  triggers = {
    name = each.value
  }
}

resource "sentry_team" "foo" {
  for_each     = [...]
  organization = ...
  name         = ...
  lifecycle {
    replace_triggered_by = [
      null_resource.example[each.key]
    ]
  }
}
```